after creating iis web.config file i have multiple header and footer
i have regular html site what work on iis. after i add web.config file, for rewrite, i have multiple header and footer.
if i not have web.config file for rewrite site work but evry time when you refresh page come 404 error. here is my html and web.config:
`<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Gaia kooli tunniplaani infosüsteem </TITLE>
<META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="Gaia kool 2024">
<META NAME="Author" CONTENT="Gaia Kool">
<META NAME="Keywords" CONTENT="Gaia kooli tunniplaani infosüsteem">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
</HEAD>

<script>
   window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
   function receiveMessage(event) {
      var urlPath = document.location.pathname;
      var lastSlashIndex = urlPath.lastIndexOf('/');
      urlPath = urlPath.substr(0, lastSlashIndex + 1) + event.data;

      window.frames['main'].location.href = document.location.protocol + '//' + document.location.host + '/' + urlPath;
   }
</script>



<frameset rows="72,50,*,30" border="0" framespacing="0" frameborder="0">
   <frame src="frames/title.htm" scrolling=no>
   <frame src="frames/navbar.htm" scrolling=no>
   <frame src="welcome.htm" scrolling=auto name="main">
   <frame src="frames/fuss.htm" scrolling=no>
</frameset>

<body>
<noframes><p>This page uses frames but your Browser does not support them.</noframes>
</body>

</HTML>`

and web.config:
`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>`

thanks for help!

Framesets are considered outdated and are generally not recommended for modern web development due to their limitations and potential accessibility issues. It's better to use CSS-based layout techniques like flexbox or grid for creating responsive and accessible web pages.

I try to reproduce your code, it seems that the webpage can run normally whether Web.config is added or not. What is i have multiple header and footer mean? And Is the Web.config (React route) you added related to Reactjs app?
